# rejectClient method in red5 not sending description to flex client

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, red5

I have built simple server side code for Red5 streaming application. Here I check if the client sends username & password while connecting from Flex.

On Server side, this is my roomConnect Code :-

```
public boolean roomConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params) {
    if (!super.roomConnect(conn, params))
        return false;

    // reject user if no username and/or password
    if(params==null || params.length<2) {
        try {
            this.rejectClient("No username/password");
        }
        catch (ClientRejectedException e) {
            log.error((String)e.getReason());
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Flex code:

```
protected function connecttored5(event:MouseEvent):void 
{   
    if(conButton.label == "Connect")
    {
        conButton.label = "Disconnect";
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.client = this;
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnect);
        nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncError);
        nc.connect("rtmp://10.117.90.248/oflaDemo/mainRoom");
    }
    else
    {
        conButton.label = "Connect";    
        nc.close();
    }
}    

protected function onConnect(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
    {   
          //carry rest of processsing

    }       
    else if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected")
    {
         trace(event.info.code);
         trace(event.info.description);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I am getting a blank string on getting **NetConnection.Connect.Reject** in Flex.
Any particular reason for not getting description ? I am intentionally not passing any arguments.

I am using :-
Red5 - 1.0.0 - RC2.
Flex 4.6

=============UPDATE==============

I have added

> trace(ObjectUtil.toString(event))

as mentioned by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756030/2829267) answer. It shows as follows:

```
info = (Array)#3947 
    [application] (null)
    [code] "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected"
    [description] ""
    [level] "error"
    [objectEncoding] 3
target = (flash.net::NetConnection)#1
type = "netStatus"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your Flex source code?

The `code` string is [NetConnection.Connect.Rejected](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html) and not *NetConnection.Connect.Reject*

**UPDATE:**

Try adding the following to your onConnect `method`:

```
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(event));
```

And does [rejectClient](https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/main/java/org/red5/server/adapter/MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter.java) return `true` or `false`?

Comment: rejectClient never returns as given [here](https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/main/java/org/red5/server/adapter/MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter.java#sl_svn4764_266)

Answer (score 0):

Check all the event.info fields; I think it may be under event.info.application or something like that.

Comment: These are the values am getting in event.info fields:
    application    : null    ***              
    code    : "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected"           ***
    description    : ""             ***
    length    : 0             ***
    level    : "error"        ***    
    objectEncoding : 3

Comment: Ill look at the source and see what i can find out.